# "on the tray" or "in the tray"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions, british-english

What is the right preposition in the following context, *on* or *in*?

> Please place the paper **on** the tray.

or

> Please place the paper **in** the tray.

Which of these would be grammatical? If both, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Depends if the speaker views the tray as a surface, where he'd use *in*, or a container, where he'd use *on*. A tray can have little walls or sides. I bet you'd find that plenty of examples of both, in the wild.

Comment: Is your tray flat (like a serving tray), or does it have raised sides, creating a partially enclosed space (like an inbox)? This will inform the answer.

Comment: @DanBron If the tray is a surface, wouldn't the paper be on it?

Comment: @vickyace As I said: depends *if* the speaker views the tray as a surface *or* if he views it as a container, and many trays can have little walls or sides, so I expect both collocations have seen plenty of use in the wild. I do not take "tray = surface" as an assumption. For example, many kinds of specialized, technical drawers are known as trays. The things that doctors put scalpels and forceps *in* in operating theaters are *trays*. Both can be used and depends on how the *speaker* conceptulalizes the tray: as 2D or 3D. There is no single "right" answer. Both are used.

Comment: @vickyace As I suspected, both are used very frequently in the wild: [Google nGram analysis of *in the tray* vs *on the tray*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+tray%2C+on+the+tray&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cin%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20Tray%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20tray%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @DanBron What!!! Words aren't enough to express my surprise. I'm just questioning the Google results henceforth.  Why would *on the tray* be used for paper that is to be placed *on/inside* of a tray with walls, however short. *On* should refer for placement on top of something. Anyways, I'll stick with regular ones.

Comment: @vickyace Mistrusting Google won't help you: the [professionally-curated BYU corpora also agree](https://imgur.com/a/iTZ6L), *in* collocates with *tray* nearly as often as *on* (the *with* there is of course indicative of phrases like "the butler came in *with* the tray") . There's no escaping it, native speakers or English frequently envision a tray as a container, not a mere surface.

Comment: @DanBron you have it backwards. *on* a surface, *in(side)* a container. The fly landed on the desk. The fly landed in the desk. The fly landed on the wall. The fly landed in my soup.

Comment: @Clare Yes, sorry, those are typos (or thinkos), you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Which **tray** are you referring to?

1. [image]

   - A flat **tray** like a dish
2. [image]

   - An ashtray (a kind of tray)
3. [image]

   - A tray with a rather high rim and a flat bottom

With all three trays you can either use **"on"** or **"in"**.

As Dan Bron commented it depends on whether one sees it a as a **"container"** or a **"flat surface"**. The only thing is wrong with Dan Bron's comment is that:

1. With a **tray** as a **container** we use **"in"** as in **"inside it"**
2. With a **tray** as a **flat surface** we use **"on"** as **"on the bottom of it"**

Examples:

- There are two cigarettes in the ashtray.
- There were a few papers left in the tray.
- There are five glasses on the tray, three of which are full.
- Jack finished his martini and put the glass on the waiter's tray.
- Please place the chicken on the tray and into the oven.

With *flat trays* or rather flat ones we mostly use **"on"**. A waiter's tray is almost always flat.

There are also *trays in which you keep paper* like those in printers. With those you use **"in"** for location and **"into"** for action.

- A maximum of 500 sheets of paper from size A6 to A4 can be loaded **into** the tray.
- There are just two more sheets left **in** the printer's tray #3.

With *picture 3* if you wish to cover the tray with bakery paper (baking paper, parchment paper) for instance then use **"in"**:

- Place the baking paper **in** the tray and put your chicken on it.

Answer (score 0):

*On* implies we care about the tray as a surface and don't see the tray as a containment mechanism, but perhaps just a transport mechanism.

A tray that servers use in a restuarant to bring multiple dishes to the table would be an example.

*In* implies the tray is containing or holding something, if it has edges that prevent things from leaving the tray, then it's "container like" and *in* can be used.

Trays with many compartments that you might find in a workshop to contain small parts would be an example.

"Deep trays" are often called pans, unless they are broad enough to be considered a "surface."

Comment: It's not that common to call a baking tray a pan in British English in my opinion. It is quite common in US English though, but the question is tagged for British English.